# check-boxes in a table added dynamically how to get id of those check boxes

Tags: html, model-view-controller, razor

I'm a bit new to mvc

I want to create an order table for a pizza ordering site
The table is populated from a database and a checkbox is add dynamically 
I want to know how i can get the ids of the checked checkboxes and add those to a list

### Model

```
 public int Ingredient_ID { get; set; }
 public string dIngredient { get; set; }
 public decimal dCost { get; set; }
 public bool add { get; set; }
```

### View

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="page-header">Choose ingredients</h2>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Ingredient
            </th>
            <th>
                Cost
            </th>
            <th>
                I want this
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dIngredient)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dCost)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!--add check box and submit-->
                    @Html.CheckBox(item.dIngredient, false, new { value = item.Ingredient_ID })

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Createorder">Place order<input />
</div>
```

how would the controller work?

Answer (score 0):

`var myArray = new Array(3);`
    `for ( var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {`
        `var check=$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox'+j+']').is(':checked');`
        `if(check==true)`
           `myArray[j]=$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox'+j+']').val();`

```
    // Alert Current Selection //
    alert('check ' + " " + myArray[j] );
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

`var myArray = new Array(10);`

`for ( var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {`

```
   ` var check=$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox'+j+']').is(':checked');`
    if(check==true)
        myArray[j]=$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox'+j+']').val();

    // Alert Current Selection //
    alert('check ' + " " + myArray[j] );
}
```

Try this It may help you